# Docker selenium nginx ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        # omitted for clarity

    php74:
        # omitted for clarity

    chrome:
        image: upshow/selenium:chromium-93
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"
            - "7900:7900"
        links:
            - "nginx:mysite.localhost"
```

No networks, no additional links, nothing. I set up nginx so it serves different sites for different hosts. Eg. I can access `mysite.localhost` from my **host** machine without any problems.

I can use selenium from inside the php74 container via http://chrome:4444

Everything works if I try to access http://nginx with the headless chrome, but when I try http://mysite.localhost, I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if you use the .localhost TLD Chrome will not try to resolve it, so it will target 127.0.0.0 instead of the container's IP address.

All credits to andrewchen5678:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1837